# Download file in Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hin 
Any ideas how to download File in Ruby i try this but it's not working

in my index.html.erb i do this

```
require 'open-uri'
def index
File.open('/target/path/to/downloaded.file', "wb") do |file|
  file.write open('http://example.com/your.file').read
end
end
```

but it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send_file should work like this:

```
send_file "/target/path/to/downloaded.file",
            :filename => "your.file",
```

also there are a few more params available:

```
            :type => 
            :x_sendfile => true
```